# Mercurial 3-way Diff Without Merging

Tags: mercurial, winmerge, kdiff3

I've got WinMerge set up to compare two arbitrary revisions like so:

> hg windiff -r 23 -r 37

I've got kdiff3 set up to be used for 3-way comparisons during merge resolution.

How does one configure mercurial to use kdiff3 to compare 3 arbitrary revisions like this:

> hg 3diff -r 23 -r 36 -r 37

I'd like to be able to get a handle on things before starting to merge or rebase.

(Is this even possible?)